# When we use FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == obtId || x.Id == pagId) which condition does it evaluate

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a file which has list of items with each item having an "Id".
My app is looking for an Id and it looks for this id in the file. The id can either be a two of the below id's  ->  `obtId` or `pagId`.

For Eg: I have `obtId=94` and `pagId=Dept` which are both present in the file. `pagId=Dept` comes intially then the `obtId=94` in the file. But I want to select the `obtId` for my page which is accurate Id from user action.

What should my query be in this case?
How can I ensure it picks the first element based on the `obtId` instead of `pagId`?

```
Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == obtId || x.Id == pagId);
```

Update:

```
 Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == obtId) ?? 
    Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == pagId);
```

This resolves my issue of searching for the obtId first, then only search for matching pagId

Comment: What file you are talking about? I see some `Items` collection only

Comment: I'm lost. I see `pagId` and `pageType`, and I see `obtId` and `objectId`, but I don't see how - if at all - they are related.

Comment: @ Sergey - The Items is a file and im checking in that file

Answer (score 2):

It evaluates as a regular if statement would in a loop.. The item returned will be the first item where the condition evaluates to true for one or both of the expressions.  If there are no items where the condition is true the default value will be returned.

Comment: Hi Regan , I have a valid id for my first expression but it returns my second expression(pagId) always. Is there something I have to check? Also the order of the Id's in my file is pagId's are first followed by ObtId's.. does it matter?

Comment: As far as the condition goes it shouldn't matter which comes first.  Though in a string of OR expressions, each expression will be evaluated from left to right until one of the conditions returns true or all expressions are exhausted.  It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve and if there is another problem else where in the code that could explain why you're not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next code:

```
var results = Items.Where(x => x.Id == objectId || x.Id == pageType).ToArray();
var result  = results.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id==objectId)??results.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id==pageType);
```

Comment: why the first statement needed?

Comment: cause author load this values from file. (I suppose there is some kind of enumerable over file rows). This code get from file only right lines and choose from right lines in memory. If we would use only second statement, there will be two enumerations over file (it is not optimal)

Comment: The OP statement is a single enumeration.  Your answer is either one or two enumerations (depending on data).  Additionally, your answer throws an exception if there is more than one result with the correct Id (not just the first result).

Comment: my code has 2 or 3 enumerations, but first is enumeration of file rows that is resource consuming and second an third enumerations of array in memory (and this array has few elements, cause it was filtered)

Answer (score 1):

```
  YourType FindMatchOrDefault(int objectId, int pageType)
  {
    YourType secondaryMatch = null;
    foreach (var x in Items)
    {
      if (x.Id == objectId)
        return x; // primary match, exit loop

      if (secondaryMatch == null && x.Id == pageType)
        secondaryMatch = x;
     }
     return secondaryMatch;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It evaluates the first, and if true, the result is true. If not, it evaluates the second, and if true, the result is true. If not, the result is false.

[Here is the MSDN page on the `||` operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)